# 1,832 Mbps connection?

Tags: bash, wget, speed-test

So this happens.

```
$ wget http://www.bing.com
--2014-01-22 21:17:42--  http://www.bing.com/
Resolving www.bing.com... 204.79.197.200
Connecting to www.bing.com|204.79.197.200|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

    [ <=>              ] 43,969      --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-01-22 21:17:43 (229 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [43969]
```

229 MB/s (=1,832 Mbps) What? What I'm trying to do is calculate my connection speed. I'm sure of two things:

1. Either we don't typically understand connection speed, or
2. *wget* is not monitoring speed correctly

My question is, can you explain this, and can you give me an easy way to monitor connection speed to see if it goes down?

Comment: Your current document should be cached on all proxies - not sure why you are unhappy about you LAN (or maybe even local box) to be fast...

Answer (score 2):

Download a bigger file.

Your 44kb file takes about a hundredth of a second to download, and this is not sufficient to accurately measure sustained throughput.

The file should download for at least 10 seconds, and you should ignore the first 5 of those.